# How to get correct stock evolution with SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have sample data and logic; I need to correct my SQL query.

#### Expected outcome:

```
ShippedData | DayEnd | DayStart  | Quantity | Daysales  | Reorderunits
------------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------
 1998-05-01 |   39   |     64    |    25    |    39     |      0
 1998-04-24 |   64   |     75    |    65    |    10     |     54
```

#### My output:

```
ShippedData | DayEnd | DayStart  | Quantity | Daysales  | Reorderunits
------------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------
 1998-05-01 |   39   |     64    |    25    |    39     |      0
 1998-04-24 |   64   |    104    |    65    |    10     |    (null)
```

## Logic

- 1st row has `DayEnd = UnitsinStock`
- 2nd row has `DayEnd` equal to the previous value of `DayStart`
- `ReorderUnits = DayEnd - DaySales`
- `DayStart = (Quantity + Daysales)`

I am getting wrong values in `DayStart` in the 2nd row: It should be 65+10 = 75
and don't know how to calculate `ReorderUnits` in the 2nd union

## Code

```
select  max(ShippedDate)ShippedDate,
        UnitsInStock as DayEnd ,
        Quantity + case when (UnitsInStock <= reorderlevel*4) then UnitsInStock
                        else reorderlevel end DayStart,
        Quantity, 
        case when (UnitsInStock <= reorderlevel*4) 
                then UnitsInStock
                else reorderlevel end DaySales,  
        UnitsOnOrder as Reorderunits 
from    dummy
where   ShippedDate = (select max(ShippedDate) from dummy) 
group by ShippedDate
union
select  ShippedDate, 
        round(previous_operation) as DayEnd, 
        DayStart,
        Quantity,
        DaySales,
        null as Reorderunits 
from    (   select  y.*, 
                    @prev AS previous_Operation,
                    @prev := Quantity + case when (UnitsInStock <= reorderlevel*4) 
                                                then UnitsInStock
                                                else reorderlevel end DayStart,
                    @prev :=  DayStart,
                    case when (@prev <= reorderlevel*4) 
                            then UnitsInStock
                            else reorderlevel end DaySales
                from    dummy  y,
                        (select @prev:=null) vars
                order by ShippedDate desc
        ) subquery_alias
where   previous_operation is not null
order by ShippedDate desc
```

Comment: Please update your question and not include images showing data definition : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Formatting your code so it's easily read leads to easier debugging. I'm having trouble making sense of your query

Comment: And please use something like SQLFiddle to show the table definition and your code alongside it: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! People already pointed out what needs improvement. I have helped you out by editing your question to deal with the first two remarks. Maybe you want to look how certain formatting was done. Now it is still up to you to provide a fiddle with the data table definition of `dummy` together with the data it would have to produce the required output.

Comment: I'm close to having something, but I'm having trouble understanding your definition of `DaySales`

Comment: DaySales is if current row of DayEnd <= reorderlevel*4 then assign  the value of  current row of DayEnd to Daysales ,else reorderlevel.In this case reorder level is 10

Comment: I don't know how to assign the current row values

Comment: Okay, I think I can work with that. If you could provide sample data and table definitions in a SQLFiddle, it would make this _much_ easier, but I'll try anyway.

Comment: Is `UnitsInStock` not equal to `DayEnd`? I see you use it as `DayEnd` for the first row. Is this true for remaining rows?

Comment: Thank you very much @Beege.I need  your help on this

Comment: Hi,Unit in stock is applicable only in the first row...for rest of the calculations,I directly have to take the previous value of DayStart as Day end

Comment: Also, which version of MySQL are you on? You can use `select @@version` to get it.

Comment: version is 5.7.10

Comment: Gotcha. There's a problem - you have circular definitions here.

`DayStart` -> `DaySales` -> `DayEnd` -> `DayStart` ... Can you define any one of these differently somehow?

Comment: Yeah:(.I could take DayEnd as Reordered units + Daysales

Comment: There's still a circle. `DaySales` <-> `DayEnd` You need an alternate way to define one of these not using the other two

Comment: and reordered units as DayEnd  - DaySales

Comment: yeah :(I don't know how to do,so complex:(

Comment: Then the problem can't be solved. Something has to break the circular dependencies. You'll need to find someone who knows more about your rules to give you an alternate definition for one of them :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort ,if at all you find something let me know:)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to compare records from the same table in order, your mind should jump to the [`rank` function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/) or [`row_number` function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/). Note that `row_number` is only available in MySQL 8.0+. Be aware that `rank` acts funny when you have duplicate values for your `order by` column in the `over` clause.

We can accomplish this by joining the table to itself based on a row number. By subtracting 1 from the row number of one of the table instances, we can get a record with two days joined to each other offset by 1 in order.

**This is an incomplete answer** because I'm having trouble understanding your definition of `DaySales`. I **think** I've captured the rest of your definitions accurately, but I can't test without sample data and table definitions.

```
select 
  current_day.ShippedDate,
  case 
    when current_day.row = 1 then current_day.UnitsInStock
    else next_day.Quantity + next_day.DaySales
  end as DayEnd,
  current_day.Quantity + current_day.DaySales as DayStart,
  current_day.Quantity,
  current_day.DaySales,
  case 
    when current_day.row = 1 then current_day.UnitsInStock - current_day.DaySales
    else next_day.Quantity + next_day.DaySales - current_day.DaySales
  end as ReorderUnits
from (
  select
    row_number() over (order by ShippedDate desc) as row,
    SOMETHING_SHOULD_GO_HERE as DaySales,
    -- ^^^ or if it's dependent on some calculation between days,
    -- calculate it in your select above
    Quantity,
    ShippedDate,
    UnitsInStock
  from dummy
) as current_day
left join (
  select
    row_number() over (order by ShippedDate desc) - 1 as row,
    SOMETHING_SHOULD_GO_HERE as DaySales, 
    Quantity
  from dummy
) as next_day
on next_day.row = current_day.row
```